# Select the latest records (i.e. ORDER by) when IDs IN multiple values

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

For example, a `devices` table like this

| id | user_id | last_used_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 111 | 2003-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 222 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 222 | 2003-01-01 00:00:00 |

- select the last used device of `user_id = 111`

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM devices
  WHERE user_id = 111
  ORDER BY last_used_at DESC
  LIMIT 1;
  -- which should select device id = 2
  ```
- select all devices of `user_id IN (111, 222)`

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM devices
  WHERE user_id IN (111, 222);
  ```

The question is - how to select the last used devices of user_id IN (111, 222)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PostgreSQL specific [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) for this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) *
FROM devices
ORDER BY user_id, last_used_at DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. Using WINDOW function is 1 of them -

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY last_used_at DESC) RN
          FROM devices)
 WHERE user_id IN (111, 222)
   AND RN = 1;
```